# Does Adding Column Delete Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I am wondering if I add a column to my table using:

```
alter table Jobs
add Complete boolean
```

Will this erase all of the data that is currently in my table? I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not at all.  This adds a column whose value is `NULL`, but it has no direct effect on the data already in the table.

As a note:  `boolean` is not a data type in SQL Server, so that particular statement will not work.  You can use `bit`, `tinyint`, `smallint`, or `int` instead.  Or a `char(1)` to store 'T' and 'F'.

And a second note:  If your table is very large, then adding a column can be take a while, because all the data may need to be rewritten.  Although the values are `NULL`, each page in SQL Server contains a bit for the `NULL` values in all the columns.  If this steps over a byte boundary, then data needs to be rearranged on the page -- and perhaps new pages allocated for the data.  In any case, each page needs to be modified to include the `NULL` values.  For this reason, it is recommended to add columns to empty tables, if possible.

Comment: Ah thank you. Yes, i just tossed this question together quick, I will be using an nvarhcar(3)

Comment: Bit is the equiv. to Boolean, 1 is true, 0 is false.  Personally, I recommend using bit fields when I need a true/false value

Comment: Yeah, dont use nvarchar(3) to hold boolean values. Bit is your best option.. In fact, arguably if you have a 3 character field, you're better off using nchar(3) rather than nvarchar(3) because the storage block to know how many characters a given field holds is two bytes and might be bigger than your data by itself. Further more, nvarchar takes up two bytes per character as opposed to varchar which is one by per character. Of course if your requrements need unicode, use whatever you need. But in general, look to the BIT data type any time you need to store booleans.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not erase your data. It will add a column and all the existing data will be assigned null values in this column.